# How can I create a service in CentOS 6?

Tags: linux, centos, services, centos-6, centos-7

I need to create ratchet service on my dedicated server (CentOS 6). I have successfully created this service on local CentOS 7. The problem is that the server has got old version of CentOS and I need to create a service there.

I have taken the following steps to create a service in CentOS 7:

Created a file named `ratchet.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/` and put the following in it:

```
[Unit]
Description=Ratchet Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php -f /path/to/ratchet/server$
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To start:

```
service ratchet start
```

Can anyone please advise how can this be achieved in **CentOS 6**?

**UPDATE:**
What i am trying to achieve is to run Ratchet Service written in php.I want to run this service on Centos 6 so that it can run persistently on my server.
I need to execute server file script (named above as /path/to/ratchet/**server.php**).

I am following this tutorial and code :
https://github.com/amirsanni/Video-Call-App

Comment: Init system in your Centos 6 is probably not `systemd` and you need to work with `/etc/init.d/` instead of systemd units. Please study [*How to find out if a system uses SysV, Upstart or Systemd initsystem*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/196166/108618), [*Detect init system using the shell*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18209/108618) and [edit] your question to tell us what it is.

Comment: Thanks @KamilMaciorowski Yes.i understand i would need to use /etc/init.d .My question was how can i write the above service in init.d in centos 6?

Comment: @FaryalGohar did you found the answer of this question? I also need this service in CENTOS 6.

Answer (score 8):

I'll provide the basic service script but anyone is invited to improve my answer.

This is for CentOS 6.10

The service scripts are placed in this directory: `/etc/rc.d/init.d`

There's a template provided by the system, open the file with your editor of choice (example vi): `vi /usr/share/doc/initscripts-*/sysvinitfiles`

Here's a simple example of my kafka script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#/etc/rc.d/init.d/kafka

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions


start() {
        echo -n "Starting kafka... "
        nohup /home/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /home/kafka/kafka/config/server.properties &
        touch /var/lock/subsys/kafka
        return 0
}

stop() {
        echo -n "Shutting down kafka... "
        nohup /home/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-server-stop.sh &
        rm -f /var/lock/subsys/kafka
        return 0
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;
    stop)
        stop
        ;;
    status)
        ;;
    restart)
        stop
        start
        ;;
    reload)
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: kafka {start|stop|status|reload|restart}"
 exit 1
        ;;
esac
exit $?
```

Based on this kafka example, this file should be saved as `/etc/rc.d/init.d/kafka`

I run it by typing: `service kafka start`

Answer (score -1):

You can write the init script logic in vi editor & save in /etc/init.d path, as shown below:-

```
vi /etc/init.d/ratchet
```

write your start/stop/restart logic here

Once done, you can start the service

```
service ratchet start
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/rachet start
```